# What is the derivative of $\text{diag}(x)^2 Ax$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a column vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, if

$$ f(x) = \text{diag}(x)^2 Ax$$

what is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$?

For now, I looked at different formulations for the $\text{diag}(x)$ function and I came up with the following:

\begin{align}
   f(x) &= \text{diag}(x)\text{diag}(x)Ax\\
        &= x \, \circ \, x \, \circ Ax\\
        &= \text{diag}(x)\text{diag}(Ax)x = \text{diag}(x)\text{diag}(x)Ax.
\end{align}
Then, the derivative should be given by:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = 2\text{diag}(x)\text{diag}(Ax) + \text{diag}(x)^2 A.
\end{equation}

Since I didn't succeed to find question involving $\text{diag}(x)^2$ and the closest being [Derivative of a function involving diagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129116/derivative-of-a-function-involving-diagonal-matrix), I was wondering if this is correct.

Also, is the following generalisation true?
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \text{diag}(x)^n Ax}{\partial x} = n\text{diag}(x)^{n-1}\text{diag}(Ax) + \text{diag}(x)^n A
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, all of your results are correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to verify!